# Will data in Chrome.Storage.Local be cleared when pc is restarted?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I've used Chrome.Storage.Local to save some data of my chrome extension. But I found that the data was gone when I restarted the computer. Is it the feature of this api? I want to know the Life cycle of data stored in Chrome.Storage.Local. Thanks.

Comment: No, it should be permanent. Post your code.

Comment: @Daniel Herr When I test my code and restart again, the data seems not lost. I do not know if I made any mistakes last time. I will delete question when I make sure there is nothing wrong with my code. thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. it will alive after reboot your computer.